# Is there any feature of programming that automatically detects computational repetition?

Tags: automation, computation

I'm new to programming, taking MIT's 6.00. While watching the [Dynamic Programming](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-3/lecture-23-dynamic-programming/) lecture a simple question occurred to me: Is there any kind of built-in feature (for computers in general) to detect repetitive tasks and compensate?

I realize that's quite vague. I was working on my grandfather's computer because he had been complaining that it was slow. Indeed, it would lag for up to 15 seconds at a time, waiting for programs to open, etc. When I upgraded the RAM, the problem was gone. So if the computer was constantly having to write page ins and page outs to disk, why couldn't it have just popped up a little message suggesting a RAM upgrade? That would save quite a bit of time.

Computers are good at performing tasks quickly but slow code can be, well, slow. Can that be automated? Is this even a legitimate question?

Answer (score 0):

In the example you describe the code isn't slow because it's reading/writing to disk. It's slow because it isn't actually doing anything but instead is waiting for the OS to page in and out to disk.

Also, a RAM upgrade isn't always the solution to frequent paging (say buggy program leaking memory or something).

It's not really possible in the general sense for the OS to detect what all the possible issues are and suggest a solution. That is in fact a variation of the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible in general for a computer to know whether a slowness was because it's running an operation that fundamentally takes a long time to finish, or whether it's taking more time than it should really be.

Also, even if you've identified that an operation is slow, it's even more difficult to diagnose the precise reason why it is slow. Sometimes it's because you need more RAM, other times because slow network, or slow disk, or slow CPU. This is even more harder if the checker is running inside the same machine that it is running on since it's also experiencing the slowness itself.

However there are several things that can be done under certain limited situations. Many popular OSes (e.g. Windows, Linux, Android) can detect slow response to user input, and will offer to either give more time or force close applications (Android) or draw the not responding window in grayscale (Linux), or in bluish tint (Windows), if the application fails to respond to user input within certain period of time.